# how to check if record inserted after a successful one in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i get some information from user and want to add it into two related tables in my database. i add first one and check it with 'insert_id' then add second one.
but problem is second 'insert_id' returns first tables inserted row id on failure. how can i check second insert query?

i'm using PHP 5, MySQL 5 and codeigniter 3

this is part of my controller:

```
$profile_result = $this->Profile_model->add($profile_data);

if ($profile_result)
{
    $host_result = $this->Host_model->add([...]);

    if (!$host_result)
        echo 'error message';
}
```

Profile_model:

```
function add($options = array())
{
    $this->db->insert("profile", $options);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

and Host_model:

```
function add($options = array())
{
    $this->db->insert("host", $options);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

$host_result never gonna be false or 0.
but how can i check whether record added to host or not?